# Need to use jQuery to show elements of an array that contains information from a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this piece of php in a file that simply takes some names from an array and prints them in a `<div>`.

```
<?php
    include "afisare.php";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($facility_names as $name)
    {
        echo '<div class="row facility-name">';
        echo '<button id="facilityName'.$count.'" class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-menu">'.$name.'</button>';
        echo '</div>';
        $count++;
    }
?>

<h1 id="facilityNameRight">Please select a facility</h1>
```

This is the other php file (afisare.php). The first part is the one that creates an array with all the names of items taken from the database and the second one takes the rest of the details for the item given as parameter to the function ($testName).

```
<?php
  include "conectare.php";
  $sql = "SELECT facility_name FROM facilities_db";
  $facility_array = array();
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $facility_array[] = $row;
  }
  $facility_names = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($facility_array));

  $dbAdapter = $mysqli;
  function getFacilities($testName) {
    global $dbAdapter;
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities_db WHERE facility_name = '$testName'";
    if (!$result1 = $dbAdapter -> query($sql1))
      die('Eroare'. $dbAdapter -> error);

    $facility_details = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
      $facility_details[] = $row;
    }
    return $facility_details;
  }

  $facility_data = getFacilities($testName);

  $facility_information = array();
?>
```

This is the jQuery that I use to edit the `<h1>` in the first php snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[id^='facilityName']").click(function(){
        $("#facilityNameRight").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Everything works well until now, BUT I want to do the following when pressing one of the buttons generated by the first php:
-Store the `$name` variable in `$facility_information[0]`
-Be able to call my `getFacilities` function with either the `$name` variable from the button or with the `$facility_information[0]`
-Print the contents of the array returned by the `getFacilities` function into the webpage using the jQuery function

To better explain myself: I want to be able to display the details for my items on the right side of the page when pressing the button that corresponds to each one of them (by getting them from the database).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand, you want to communicate via AJAX? Its in the same page?

Comment: They are not on the same page! The first php is written inside the whole webpage, the second one is another .php.

Comment: Fun fact, not related to your question but it's a nice little tip. Where you have done `echo '<button id="facilityName'.$count.'"` and then `$count++;` on another line. You can simply just do `echo <button id="facilityName'.$count++.'"` and then you wouldn't need the separate `$count++` line

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you take the class from the buttons. In your case:

```
$(".btn-menu").click(function(){
    $("#facilityNameRight").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: No, because I only need that function to work for the buttons whose ids start with that exact string.